# ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 1020 bytes. Largest size supported is 900 bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here it is some following lines of sql code:

```
SELECT cd.continent, cd.location, cd.date, cd.population, cv.new_vaccinations,
    SUM(CONVERT(int, cv.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by cd.location
    Order by cd.location, cd.date)
FROM [Project Covid Analysis]..covid_death$ as cd
JOIN [Project Covid Analysis]..Covid_Vaccine$ as cv
    ON cd.date=cv.date 
AND cd.location=cv.location
WHERE cd.continent IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 2,3
```

After execute those lines, I got an error message "ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 1020 bytes. Largest size supported is 900 bytes." I think the syntax has already correct. Please, if anybody know how to overcome this. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `location` and `date` combined contain long texts over 900 byte which is the limit to `order by`.

Comment: Ordering by `location` is pointless when you partition by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most likely you didn't want a `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` window frame anyway, but unfortunately that is the default.**

Instead use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`

```sql
SUM(CONVERT(int, cv.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by cd.location
    Order by cd.location, cd.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

Although as noted, if you partition by a value there is no point ordering by it also.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory: you cannot have `order by` columns in an `over` clause whose total size exceeds 900 bytes.

Here's an example that replicates your error message:

```sql
drop table if exists [dbo].[Example1];
create table [dbo].[Example1] (
  [Location] varchar(1017),
  [Date] date
);
select
  [Location],
  [Date],
  sum(1) over (partition by [Location] order by [Location], [Date]) as [Sum]
from [dbo].[Example1];

-- Msg 8729 Level 16 State 1 Line 6
-- ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 1020 bytes. Largest size supported is 900 bytes.
```

Reduce the size of your Location column so that the total size is less than or equal to 900 bytes, e.g.:

```sql
drop table if exists [dbo].[Example2];
create table [dbo].[Example2] (
  [Location] varchar(897),
  [Date] date
);
select
  [Location],
  [Date],
  sum(1) over (partition by [Location] order by [Location], [Date]) as [Sum]
from [dbo].[Example2];
```

Comment: Why not just remove `Location` from the `ORDER BY`? If I gave you 1,000 integers between 1 and 10, and ask you to put them into groups, and then order those integers in numerical order in their group, you're always done; all the integers in the group are the *same*.

Comment: I upvoted your comment on the question earlier because I agree. My answer is addressing the source of the error message.